# finding the index of a tag in html using selenium(python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots

am trying to find an index or something similar, I want to find a certain word and then click the link under it that belong  to the one after it
sorry if it's[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IxFH.png) not understandable I will put an image maybe it will be more understandable

Comment: Pls copy paste the html code in the question. And this much of html code would not be enough to find out the solution. Pls provide at least 10-20 lines of the relevant html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to get an element in selenium, you could also use Relative Locators.

[Relative locators](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/#relative-locators) allow finding nearby objects.

As for indexes, Xpaths have index-like numbers in them. you can manipulate those to get to a diff element in your website's array.

To get your element's Xpath: Right click your object > Select "Inspect" > copy > copy full Xpath.

Then, store that XPath in a variable.
Now, we can change numbers inside your xpath:

```
#define xpath
variable = '/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/input'

#loop through 10 elements
for i in range(10):
   variable = f'/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[5]/div/input'
```

You will need to figure out which numbers in your xpath need to be changed.

This code will click on that element:

```
ClickHere = driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable).click()
```

This code will store the text of that element in a variable:

```
Text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable).text
```

Comment: Thank u very much